# Vue reactivity problem when removing index

Tags: arrays, vue.js, indexof, vue-reactivity

I have a little vue app with 3 buttons

```
<button @click="add(1)">1</button>
<button @click="add(2)">2</button>
<button @click="add(3)">3</button>
```

The number is added to an array

so typically you can get

```
[1,2,3,1,3]
```

I output these as a list

```
<div class="numbers" v-for="(number, index) in numbers">
  <span @click="removeNumber(index)">{{ number }}</span>
</div>
```

However my remove number method does this

```
removeNumber(index) {

  Vue.delete(this.numbers, index ); // I have also used splice here

},
```

The data (numbers) shows the correct result however the UI always removes the last item not the one I want.

so if I had

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
```

and I tried to remove number 2. The data would be correct but the UI ALWAYS just removes number 3.

I suspect this is a reactivity issue but cannot solve it. I tried also to wrap the Vue.delete in a nextTick()

Comment: You pasted `Vue.delete(this.number, index );`. That should be `this.numbers` with the plural, right?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, you are of course correct.

Comment: I made this pen with -I believe is- your code, and everything is working as expected: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPPvKZ

Comment: Thanks, that is strange and works I even modified it so the buttons are created from an array(as they are in my app). Thanks for your help maybe I have to rethink why the I am getting this strange side-effect.

Comment: It might help to include the exact code that you're using.